# Can I travel through Greece with UK emergency travel document/passport

Tags: international-travel, uk-citizens, greece, emergencies, iata

I was traveling from South Africa to the United Kingdom through Greece.UK embassy and Greek Embassy prior to purchasing the ticket confirmed the emergency passport was valid for entry, transit and exit through Greece and no visa was required. Additionally, I had tickets already booked and checked-in from Greece to UK in 4 hours' time as the lay over.

According to the airline, Greece does not accept UK citizens traveling with an emergency passport/travel document and demanded I purchase another ticket. Following up on this via email they stated the IATA timatic regulations (image attachment).

Please can someone with the knowledge advise me on the attached image. My conclusion from what I read is that UK emergency passport holders are exempt from producing a normal passport and a visa for entry into Greece; which is in keeping with what I have been told by both embassies.

Please assist and thank you in advance.[image: IATA Timatic requirements]

Comment: Are you presenting the airline a **single** ticket that includes the layover (without going through passport control)? With 2 **seperate** tickets, airlines often assume that you are entering the Schengen Area (i.e. going through passport control).